# How to compare objects in controller using IF symfony2 PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, controller, symfony

I am a beginner at symfony programming and I am curious how can I compare two objects in controller.
This is how my page looks like: https://gyazo.com/bab9d948bdb7a2ae3375feb553ce07b2

At the top left there is my money amount and I want to buy a car which has its own price. Amount of money has its own place in a database and car have separate one. By pressing Buy Car it opens a form which look like this: https://gyazo.com/58582c628d8507e6b3eac48a7645f2a1

There is two options: Back which redirects to front page and Delete(Buy) which deletes car from database.
This is how function in controller looks like:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Car $car){
$form = $this -> createFormBuilder($car)
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class,['label' => 'DELETE'])
        ->getForm();

    $form2 = $this -> createFormBuilder($car)
        ->add('save2',SubmitType::class,['label' => 'BACK'])
        ->getForm();


    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form2->handleRequest($request);
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        $em = $this ->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $baze = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Produktas')->find(1);
       $price =$car->getPrice();



      if($price < $baze) {
        $baze->setKaina($baze->getKaina() - $price);
           $em->remove($car);
     }

        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('car_index');
    }
```

The question is: How can I compare two objects in if in a appropriate way? I want to make if(my money>Car Price){I CAN BUY IT}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first I would change your back link to am usually link, not an form.

Your mistake in the condition is to check if price and the `Produktas` is equal. I think you forget the getPrice method here.

But I would do this with a immutable object. Create a New money object, check this out at: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html

I would suggest to create a Pocket entity and use the money entity in it.

Now you can define the price in your car entity with the same money entity.

In your car entity you should define a method called:
`isBuyable(Pocket $pocket)`. Here you should check that  money value is greather than or equals as the money object inside of the car entity and return true if conditions matches.

In your controller you dann use now The isBuyable method.

Additionally you can create a new method in your car repository and fetch only cars that buyable, take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

Hope it helps, 
Cheers, 
Robin